# Why doesn't the water from netilas yadayim immediately make your hands impure again?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, netilat-yadayim-washing, water

I believe it's a mishna in Yadayim that says the first pour for netilas yadayim purifies the hand and the second pour purifies the water that's left on the hand. Hands are considered shniyim letumah and when water touches them it becomes rishon letumah. My question is, why doesn't the water (which is rishon letumah before the second pour) that's left on the hand just immediately make the hands impure once again as shniyim letumah?